# Where is my Excel file on Android saved?

Tags: android, excel, storage

I have this code which makes new Excel file.
The file is blank, it only creates a sheet.
Code goes like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Havaji");
    Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Hi there");
    try{
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test2.xls");
        workbook.write(output);
        output.close();
    }
    ...
```

Where is that file saved ?
How to manage to save a file on the location on the mobile device that i want?
How to create a directory where all the files are gonna be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few methods you'll find useful for your purposes:

Creates all the directories along the path provided:

```
    public static boolean createPath(String path) {
    File pathFile = new File(path);
    if (!pathFile.exists()) {
        boolean result = pathFile.mkdirs();
        if (!result) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create directory path: " +
             path);
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (!pathFile.isDirectory()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Returns the root of the external storage directory:

```
public static String extDirectory() {
    File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Returns the path to the root of an application's external storage directory:

```
public static String externalMyAppDataRoot(Context context) {
    return externalAppDataRoot() + File.separatorChar
            + context.getPackageName() + File.separatorChar + "data";
}
```

Returns the path to the root of the Android application data directory:

```
public static String externalAppDataRoot() {
    return extDirectory() + File.separatorChar + "Android/data";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that is being stored in /data/app//files/Test2.xls, though i'm not completely sure

I would try to pass in an absolute file path. If you want the file to be in the sdcard, i would use the [Context.getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)  to get the root path of the sdcard.